# Upcoming Birthdays custom search not working

Tags: custom-search

I have followed the instructions to install the "Upcoming Birthdays" customer search from [here.](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upcoming+Birthday+and+Anniversary+searches)

However, when I run this custom search, CiviCRM gives me blank screen. Our organization is using CiviCRM 4.6.2 on Wordpress 4.1.5. Is this customer search working on 4.6?

Is there another way I could create a search for up and coming birthdays for our members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is via the [Upcoming Birthdays Report](https://civicrm.org/extensions/upcoming-birthday-report) extension.

Comment: Ok. But I don't see this extension listed within CiviCRM - How do I install it manually?

Comment: You unzip it into your extensions directory.  You'll need FTP or SSH access to your server.  You can find your extensions directory by checking **Administer menu » System Settings » Directories**.  If you need more assistance with this, please open another question, since it's a separate issue.

Comment: Ok. I managed to install the extension successfully. Found some further help on the extension directory at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16610/where-is-civicrm-installed/16611#16611

Answer (score 1):

You can now use [Relative Dates](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/the-user-interface/searching/) (see "Date Range Filter" section) against the Date of Birth field in Advanced Search.  This custom search is no longer necessary now that relative dates are available.  Note that in the next version of CiviCRM (4.7), relative date filters will be configurable.

Also, as of CiviCRM 4.6, Date of Birth can now be used as a criterium for sending [Scheduled Reminders](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/email/scheduled-reminders/).
[image]

Comment: Ok. How do I configure or use relative dates to give me the up and coming birthdays? For example, we want to send a birthday card via postal mail to all members who have birthdays in June 2015. For this we need to find those contacts, and then generate mailing labels.

Comment: @Sudesh - Use Advanced Search, set "Birth Dates" to "Next Month".  I've edited my answer to include a screenshot.

Comment: I have already tried the "Birth Dates" set to "Next Month", but the search does not find anything. As a test, I created a test contact and set the contacts birth date to 18 June 1996. I performed the advanced search and again, no results were returned. My test contact does not show up. I then modified the test contact's birth date to 18 June 2015. Running the search again, now shows this contact in the search results. So it seems that Civi is searching for actual birth dates, as apposed to birth "days". For birthdays, we are just interested in the day and month, not the actual year.

Comment: @ Jon. I've tried to work around this, by creating a custom field for admin staff to select the contacts birth month. Then in advanced search, I can select the birth month as a criterion and it works well. However, it means that admin staff need to now enter the birth date under demographics and make a second entry of the birth month under our custom fields tab. So, it like a double entry. So, I would still like to know if relative dates can still be used somehow to perform this task.

Comment: @Sudesh - You're right, you can't handle this via Relative Date Filters.  You CAN handle this using scheduled reminders.  I'm working on an overhaul to relative date filters - I don't know if we'll have time to implement this use case, but I'll definitely keep it in mind.

Comment: @ Jon - Following up on this again. Do we have the ability in 4.7 to find upcoming birthdays?

Comment: @sudesh see my new answer.