# How can I send "Birthday wish" email to contact?

Tags: civimail

I have tried to create a smart group for the contact who's birthday is today and send an email via civirules, but search builder doesn't have option to set the date as "Today".

Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Just wondering if anyone has worked on a similar flow and give a hint please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scheduled reminders functionally works nicely with any date field. -

[image]

Comment: Awesome idea! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I would not use a smart group, but use the "Individual has birthday" trigger that is included in CiviRules?

Comment: How would you configure the Birthday Rule to trigger 1 day before the birthday?

Comment: Hmmm not sure that would be feasible without coding with the birthday trigger.

Comment: Is there a generic CiviRule condition that can be used to trigger something a set number of days before a recorded date? Like if you have a scheduled activity at 01.april (and not birthday), you can have it to trigger -7 days, so you have the possibility to mail something abroad...?

Comment: No there is not. The delay is with the action, so you can set a delay of 7 days for an action but there is not something like : do this x days before this date. Can be developed though if there is either a contributor that is happy to do that or someone who is willing to fund it.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Adv Search then you can get the Today option on the birth date. Your question doesn't explain why it needs to be via Search Builder hence 'using Adv Search' seems to be a valid answer to 'is there an alternative way'.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking too far ahead but didnt realise that adv search has that option already.

Comment: On a second thought, it still doesnt give me a feasible option to create a workflow for email. Birthday “today” doesnt really pullup any result. Because it’s looking for a actual date with year. Whereas I am looking for a month and date rather. Then it would be possible to complete the sending email flow.

Comment: does the answer here help you at all https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/2307/96